VS Code not taking input while running Java program
While taking input from the user using Java, program is running successful and Visual Studio Code does asks user to input, but when I try to enter anything like a number or a character, it takes no input.
I tried a minutes into years and days program and my code is working fine but when I take input from the user, it takes no input and then I have to stop the program.

If you're working with one language, please don't tag other unrelated languages. How is your Java program related to C++?

Also please read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist. Then [edit] your question to show us a [mre] of the code you have, copy-pasted as text.

Duplicate of Unable to get User input for the Java program written in Visual Studio Code Editor

I think you may be using the Code Runner extension to execute the script (Run Code), which causes the program results to be output in the OUTPUT panel, which does not accept user input.
You should use the official extension Extension Pack for Java to execute the script (Run Java), which will output the results in the TERMINAL and can accept input.


In general, Code Runner's limitations are extremely, uh, limiting. You better off using almost anything else.
